# API key in Angular Ionic

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, api-key

I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/loading-remote-json-data-with-http-in-ionic-2/) since we are using JSON format as our data. In order to call our API via URL, API key needs to be set to get/read the data. Is there any way that I can set the API key or to set the Headers to my Angular Ionic APP so that I can get and read the data from our API URL just like we conduct our testing using postman?

[image]

Here's my code for data.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  url = '';
  apiKey = ''; // <-- Enter your own key here!

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    getLocalData(){
      return this.http.get("assets/data/data.json");
    }

    getRemoteData(){
      return this.http.get('{this.url}&apiKey=${this.apiKey}');
    }
}
```

Here's my code for page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-status',
  templateUrl: './status.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./status.page.scss'],
})
export class StatusPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getLocalData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Local Data:");
      console.log(data);
    });

    this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Remote Data:");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it as HttpHeaders, So you need to use

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('apiKey', this.apiKey);
```

or

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({'apiKey': this.apiKey});
```

You can set it as,

```
this.http.get(this.apiUrl, {headers: headers})
```

Comment: Thanks! but currently I'm experiencing a 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET' error

Comment: It means url is wrony